# change to decorator pattern

Tags: python

I'm learning decorators and here I'm trying to change the below to decorator pattern.

```
def invert(x):
    return 1/x

print invert(5)
```

can be changed using decorators.

```
def safe(fun, *args):
    if args[0]!=0:
        return fun(*args)
    else:
        "Division by 0"

def invert(x):
    return 1/x

print safe(invert, 5)
```

Using @wapper syntax,

```
def safe(fun, *args):
    if args[0]!=0:
        return fun(*args)
    else:
        "Division by 0"
@safe
def invert(x):
    return 1/x

print invert(5)
```

The above code gives error `IndexError: tuple index out of range`. I'm trying to understand what makes it wrong and how to correct it.

Comment: Please defined what you mean by **wrong** - give the error or incorrect result you receive.

Comment: `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem is that a decorator needs to return a function, not a value. The decorator replaces the defined function with a new one based on it.

Beyond that, you do not have a `return` statement in the `else` block, merely a string literal. You probably meant to return that.

```
def safe(fun):
    def f(*args):
        if not args[0] == 0:
            return fun(*args)
        else:
            return "Division by 0"
    return f
```

Just as a note, I presume this is for the purposes of the exercise only, but *errors should not pass silently* in Python - the behaviour of emitting an exception is far more useful in general than returning a string on error. In fact, to implement this more naturally for Python you want to follow a *ask for forgiveness, not permission* mantra:

```
def safe(fun):
    def f(*args):
        try:
            return fun(*args)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            return "Division by 0"
    return f
```

Also, be careful of sweeping statement names like 'safe' - other exceptions could still be thrown.

Comment: I have seen examples were they use a class instead of a function to wrap around the original function. When do we need to go for that approach?

Comment: @John You should do that if your wrapper function needs to have some sort of memory, like if you want to do [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) for example. It's not that you *have to*, but some times it's tidier to use a class, or a [functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object), as it would be called when used like that.

Comment: In general it's a case of, if you need to use it, you'll know you need to.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing it wrong.

```
def safe(fun):
    def wrapper(*args)
        if args[0]!=0:
            return fun(*args)
        else:
            return "Division by 0"
    return wrapper
```

The function `safe` is called *once* for each function you decorate with it. The inner function, which is returned by `safe` -- here called `wrapped` -- is then called each time the decorated function is called. It is responsible for calling the original function, or doing something else entirely.

So a decorator takes exactly one argument: the function to be wrapped. *BUT*, there are decorator *functions*, which is a function returning a decorator (so one more layer of wrapped functions):

```
def safe(singularities):
    def decorator(fun):
        def wrapper(*args)
            if args[0] not in singularities:
                return fun(*args)
            else:
                return "Division by 0"
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

So the `safe` decorator function may now return an infinite number of different decorators. Use like this:

```
@safe([0])
def invert(x):
    return 1 / x

@safe([-1, 1])
def foo(x)
    return 1 / ((x - 1) * (x + 1))
```

*For those wondering why I've posted essentially the same answer as Lattyware after he posted his: That answer did not address all the issues until after I started writing mine, and now I've added more information than is in his, so I will not delete it, since it is not an outright duplicate.*

Comment: @Lattyware Wohoo! Thank you for pushing me over 5000! :)

Comment: @lazyr I'm glad I can introduce you to the fun world of approving tag wiki edits ;)